# python package versioning, using a higher version of a package than another dependency with a lower package version

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider Project A requirements.txt (project name being foo-bar-a)

```
pyspark==3.1.2
```

Consider Project B requirements.txt

```
foo-bar-a
pyspark==3.3.4
```

There are a few projects that are using project repo a Python package, so we cant directly update the pyspark package version here. My understanding is that since pyspark 3.1.2 is a dependency of project a, project b could override this value using a higher version of pyspark. Is this true?

Currently, what actually exists in repo a is `pyspark~=3.1.2`, so attempting the above in project b, yielded a dependency resolution error because the `~=` prevents going higher than `3.1.x`. But if that gets swapped for `==`, could we then override in project b?

```
 The conflict is caused by:
      The user requested pyspark==3.3.4
      project a 0.0.1 depends on pyspark~=3.1.2
```

Comment: `==` is stricter than `~=`; you want `>=` to allow *any* later version of `pyspark`, including bumps in the minor or even major version. But that's for Project *A*; if you can't change A, then you can't use A with a project that wants a later version.

Comment: @chepner but wouldnt that mean that any projects using project a would bump to the latest version? Another way I'm thinking about it, is that any project using project-a package should stick with 3.1.2 unless otherwise bumped in its own project.

Comment: No, because Project A is specifically saying it *can't* work with the latest version. If it could work with 3.1.2 or later, it would say `pyspark>=3.1.2`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/version-specifiers/#version-specifiers, `~=` is equivalent to a combination of `>=` and `==` which pins a "prefix" of the version number while allowing the suffix to increase.

`pyspark==3.1.2` requires *exactly* version 3.1.2, no exceptions.

`pyspark~=3.1.2` requires "exactly" version 3.1.x, but at least 3.1.2. (You could upgrade to 3.1.3, for example, but not 3.2.)

What you want in Project A, then, is `pyspark>=3.1.2`, which will allow *any* version of `pyspark` later than 3.1.2: 3.1.3, 3.2, even 4. Unless there is a known conflict, it's better not to constrain versions with upper bounds.

A good use for `==` is in a lock file, where you have already resolved any combined dependencies, and what to record exactly what *has been* installed in an environment, rather than dictate what *must* be installed.

Comment: So `>=` in project A would install 3.1.x, giving security patches, and would allow any other project to override pyspark by placing pyspark with a higher version afterwards.

Could you unpack `Unless there is a known conflict, it's better not to constrain versions with upper bounds.` more?

Comment: As far as I know, a dependency resolver will *always* try to choose the latest version allows. If the requirement is `pyspark>=3.1.2` and `pyspark-3.3.4` is available, it will *always* choose `pyspark-3.3.4` over an earlier version, unless some other project specifies an upper bound.

Comment: Regarding upper bounds, you wouldn't specify, say, `python <= 2.7` unless your code used `print` statements or other *known* backwards compatibility issue with Python 3. In general, *assume* that later versions will be backwards compatible, and only cap the allowable version once you *know* it is incompatible.